# Getting a lag in updating UI controls when some processing done in DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, dispatch-queue

Trying to update UI controls from the DispatchQueue.main.async closure that does some processing and takes a few hundred milli seconds or more, there is a lag in the update of the UI labels of a few to several seconds.  If there is no delay or the delay is short, the update of the labels in the UI occurs as the code is run and appears to be instantaneous.

I have this small example to illustrate the issue where I've added a 'wait in millisecs' func to simulate processing time taken and show the UI update lag occurring.

In the example, the waitForMilliSecs is set to 300 or less, the labels are updated instantaneously.  Any number greater than 300, the delay in updating the labels of a few to many seconds occurs.   The log messages are there to indicate that the code has run and ideally the UI should be updated as they are printed out.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           os_log("before")
           self.label1.text = "updated label 1 1111"
           self.label2.text = "updated label 2 2222"
           self.waitForMilliSecs(MilliSecs: 300)
           os_log("after")
       }

}

func waitForMilliSecs(MilliSecs millisecs: Int) -> Void {
    var date = NSDate()
    let firstTime = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    var currentTime = firstTime
    while currentTime - firstTime < millisecs {
        date = NSDate()
        currentTime = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

The real use case is that I'm scraping an HTML page for data and then updating the UI with some of the contents of the page.   The completion handler is called from the URLSession.shared.dataTask on a background thread so the DispatchQueue.main.async closure is being used to update the UI on the main thread.

Is there a better way to do update the UI?   Is there a way to force the update of events on the Main thread?

Comment: UI updates are done on the main thread. Anything that consumes enough time to slow the UI updates can and should be done on alternate threads. Process your HTML page on the background thread, then update the UI elements on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the input.   I put the html page retrieval code into the DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async thread and I'm getting better results now.

Comment: If this is a "new delay" and you're running the latest iOS versions it's possible you're seeing the slowdown Apple added as a result of their battery problem.  We've seen several issues running the latest OS so you might be experiencing it as well.

Comment: I am running the latest OS version.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't better way to update UI than on main thread.

But what you do is not exactly correct. You do processing on main thread as well (function waitForMilliSecs). This is perhaps not what you want.
You need to do processing on background thread, and when that processing is done, update UI on main thread.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
       print("before")
       //this function is doing some real work and produces some results.
       self.waitForMilliSecs(MilliSecs: 3000)
       print("after")

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.label1.text = "updated label 1 1111"
            self.label2.text = "updated label 2 2222"
       }
    }
}
```

github repo showing whole example:
https://github.com/jurajantas/TestOfBackgroundProcessing.git

Comment: I put this code into my test app and it still had the random few to many second delay on updating the labels in the UI.    I would expect that after the wait delay of X milli seconds, the UI would update.  But it doesn't.   Is my assumption incorrect on when the update should occur?

Comment: update of UI happens after you see "after" in the log console.

Comment: if you have latest xcode (9.2) there is new feature called Thread sanitizer. It will warn you when you update UI from background thread. If you do update UI from background thread, you can see that update happened slower (aslo it is not thread safe). More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/thread_sanitizer/enabling_the_thread_sanitizer

Comment: The label update happens from a few to several seconds after the 'after' is printed.  I would expect the label to update and the same time as the print 'after' occurs.   I use xcode 9.2 and have seen the warning on the ui update in the wrong thread.   This no longer occurs though with the changes with the back ground thread.  BTW, thanks for you comments

Comment: I created github repo that shows how it works. UI updates immediately. https://github.com/jurajantas/TestOfBackgroundProcessing.git

Comment: Thanks for the example code and the info that this works for you.  I downloaded the test, ran it, and unfortunately, got the same results of the label update taking several seconds to occur.  The print statements indicated execution timing and the label update occurred several seconds after the print statement 'after'.   Could this issue be a hardware or mac os config issue?

Comment: hard to tell what is the issue, but it clearly isn't the code. Make sure you download genuine software from Apple. There was a time when downloaded Xcode from 3rd. party had malware included. I would be surprised if this happen agin and now it mine some crypto currency in background. If you are using libraries from 3rd parties make sure you understand what they are doing. Sometimes you can get more that you asked for.

Comment: thanks for the input and your time.  If I find the cause I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Main Thread is synchronous. In you example you are loading main thread with loop, blocking UI to update.

As for your real use case - all UI had to be updated in Main Thread (otherwise some unpredictable artefacts can happened including partial updates and unexpected colour changes). GCD (DispatchAsyn) is most natural way to do it, however lot of 3rd parties available to simplify asynchronous operations. Like https://cocoapods.org/pods/ResultPromises

Comment: THanks for the info on the 3rd party tools to assist with this type of action.  I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

When you use a value of 300 in the `waitForMilliSecs` function, it appears instantaneous but it is not. It's just a small enough time that you aren't noticing that the UI has locked up while your code is spinning on the main thread.

The reason why the text does not update immediately after calling `self.label1.text = "updated label 1 1111"` is because UI changes don't take place immediately. The UI updates at a particular rate (60hz or 120hz). Every change you make will become visible on the screen in the next render cycle.

Checkout the CPU usage during the 300ms slice when it was waiting. You'd see it spike close to 100% which is a really bad thing to do.

What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is retrieve a web page, extract data from the page and then set the data into some labels and update a table.    Inside the viewDidLoad() method, I put the URLSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:...) into a DispatchQueue.global(qos:...).async() closure to ensure that the request was in the background.  The completion handler has DispatchQueue.main.async{} around the UILabels and table.reloadData() calls.

Comment: The UI update though has delays though that takes from a few to several seconds to update the UI.  I watched the threads and calls in the debugger and the calls seemed to be on the corrrect background and main threads.   Why I tried the wait loop was to test when this issue occurs   My page retrieval and processing of the HTML takes about .5-.7 milli seconds and I was trying to see if this was a timing issue.

Comment: correction: should be '.5-.7 seconds', not .5-.7 milli seconds

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CADisplayLink?  It calls a screen refresh every 60 secs by default (this solved some of my problems): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

```
let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI))
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)
```

And then:

```
@objc func updateUI() {
    print("Updating UI!")
}
```